# no verp, what to do

Tags: civimail

I am struggling setting up bounce handling with my webhost who can't handle VERP.
I have set up a catch-all mail account with filter, and all bounced messages sent my civimail arrive in this account.
I can send emails, cronjob(fetch bounces) seems successful, but nothing appears in bounce reports.
In the account somehow a new folder appeared called Civimail and has 2 subfolders: ignored and processed
The bounce mails don't even have unique ID in their header. They look like this:
"delivered-to:contact+INBOX@mydomain.com"
What am I missing here? According to this is should work: https://flossmanualsfr.net/civicrm/email-system-configuration/

I only have Cpanel to work with.

Answer (score 1):

For current documentation, see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/

How are you sending your mails out?  If you use a service like Mailgun or SparkPost then there are extensions to handle the bounces without needing to configure your own bounce inbox processing.

Comment: I am using plain SMTP, so I think I need to configure this somehow. I just need more info as the description in the linked docs don't seem to work:-(